# Error 415 (Unsupported Media Type) when sending content to Jersey Rest endpoint

Tags: java, ajax, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a Java Jersey class on the backend of my project which has the goal to consume a MULTIPART_FORM_DATA sent from an ajax frontend. When I send the data, I receive a 415 (Unsupported Media Type), even though the content type is formatted as:

content-type: multipart/form-data;

My backend method is configured as follow:

`@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) 
@Path("/fileupload")`enter code here
`public Response uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition cdh,@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileStream) {
    System.out.println("hello there");
    Payment newPayment = new Payment();
    return Response.ok().entity(newPayment).build();
}`

Ajax code is configured as follow:

`$.ajax({
                       url: '/path/api/fileupload',
                       type: "POST",
                       data: formData,
                       processData: false,
                       contentType: false,
                       success: function(response) {
                           alert("hello there")
                       },
                       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                           alert(errorMessage); // Optional
                       }
                    });`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have contentType set to false, it may be that the REST service is expecting MULTIPART_FORM_DATA and you're not sending that explicit contentType.

`@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)` means you need to pass an explicit contentType of `"multipart/form-data"`, which you are not doing, you are passing `"false"`.

Comment: When I check the log, I see that content-type is set to multipart/form-data1 > accept: */*
1 > accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
1 > accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8,es;q=0.7
1 > connection: keep-alive
1 > content-length: 44
1 > content-type: multipart/form-data;

Comment: Have you tried explicitly stating the contentType as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, I have tried and it hasnt worked. I am using a formData as the object data and according to the following answer, we should set content type to false on that situation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: Post the line of code where you actually initialize `formData` to be a `FormData()` object.

Comment: var fileSelect = document.getElementById('file-select');
var files = fileSelect.files;
var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
 var file = files[i];
 formData.append('photos[]', file, file.name);
}

Comment: Hmm, only thing I can think of is that the file is not actually in a form? or something is malformed. Or, maybe you're using an old browser version? I don't think that's the case because you seem to have read the answer to that question you linked and it specifically talks about what browser versions it is available in.